# Get a users timeline from the Facebook API

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, api

I'm currently using this piece of code to get a users feed from Facebook:

```
FBRequest *friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?fields=cover,first_name,last_name,relationship_status,feed", self.friendID] parameters:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"en_EN", @"locale", nil] HTTPMethod:nil];
    [friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  NSDictionary* result,
                                                  NSError *error) {

        postsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[result valueForKeyPath:@"feed.data"]];
        [tableView reloadData];
        NSLog(@"Data found: %@", [result description]);
        NSLog(@"Posts: %i", postsArray.count);
           }];
```

However, this 'feed' also includes things like 'XXX on his own post' or 'User A liked Post B' and I'd like to get just what the user has posted and what others have posted onto his wall (like if you go to a user timeline on facebook.com or in the iOS apps). Is that possible? If not, how can I found out if a status is a 'like' or 'commented on...'?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the read_stream permission and FQL

Documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream)

You can loop through results and find where `type` is equal to:

```
46 - Status update
56 - Post on wall from another user
```

Comment: Thanks, got it working. But 'type' always returns null... `FBRequest *fql = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"fql"];
    [fql.parameters setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT post_id, viewer_id, app_id, source_id, updated_time, created_time, filter_key, attribution, actor_id, target_id, message, app_data, action_links, attachment, impressions, comments, likes, place, privacy, permalink, xid, tagged_ids, message_tags, description, description_tags, type FROM stream WHERE source_id=%@ LIMIT 50", self.friendID] forKey:@"q"];`